# Stuck winform while running 3 processes /thread failures

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am new to threads in windows form. i am developing an one form application which shows message sending option  along with live video stream in web browser and a live pulse plot using charts. I can successfully run these processes separately in other form but now i want to embed all in one form but as soon as app runs it hangs only showing video feed and cursor cant move in form. I need some one to guide me in threading. Thankyou

This is my desired form and code. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClientApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string myMessage = "";
        private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new 
                                            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("server 
                                            ip"), port1);
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
            socket.Connect("server ip", port2);


            //thread for running video stream
            Thread t1 = new Thread(threadURL);
            t1.Start();

        }

        void threadURL()
        {
            string URL = "server ip";
            webBrowser2.Navigate(URL);
        }


        // now the chat part(send message to Rpi)

        private void RtbClientKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyData != Keys.Enter || e.KeyData != Keys.Return)
            {
                myMessage += (char)e.KeyValue;
            }
            else
            {

                SendMessage(myMessage);
                myMessage = "";

            }

        }

        private void SendMessage(string msg)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(msg);

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();


        }

        //realtime pulse plot part received from socket
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer chartTimer = new 
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        private void InitChart()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            chartTimer.Interval = 1000;
            chartTimer.Tick += chartTimer_Tick;
            chart1.DoubleClick += chartDemo_DoubleClick;

            Series series = chart1.Series[0];


            chartTimer.Start();

        }

        //socket receiving pulse values from Rpi
        int ReceiveText()
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int iRx = socket.Receive(buffer);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx];

            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            string recv = new string(chars);
            int final = Convert.ToInt16(recv);

            return final;

        }


        void chartDemo_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 5;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        }


        private void LivePulseplot()
        {

            Series series = chart1.Series[0];
            chartTimer.Start();

            series.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), 
                                                      ReceiveText());
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = series.Points.Count - 5;

        }


        void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Thread tP = new Thread(LivePulseplot);
            tP.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using threads is fine - however its a bad call to update the UI from the thread this will result in odd activities however your timer is creating a new thread each tick, you could very much end up with a race condition

Comment: could you please elaborate race condition? and what possible solution do you suggest?

Comment: race condition is trying to update the same thing at the same time from more than 1 thread

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your form hangs is that the main thread (the one that created and is rendering the UI) is working all the time.

You have a few possibilities to prevent this from happening. 
One is to start threads which do stuff in the background (although that can be tricky because you need to ensure that anything that updates the UI delegates that responsibility to the UI thread, because other threads are not allowed to change something created on the main thread), as you do in your code, and others are using the async/await pattern or e.g. BackgroundWorkers.

There are a few problems in your implementation.
In chartTimer_Tick you are starting a new thread. This will happen every time the timer ticks (which is every 1000 ms). You shouldn't call chartTimer.Start() in LivePulsePlot, since the timer is already running (or you wouldn't hit that function). Once you've called Start() on the timer, it will continue executing its 'Tick' function every 1000 ms, until you call Stop().

Also, System.Windows.Forms.Timer executes its method on the UI thread, which will cause the UI to freeze while the function is running. You can use a different timer, e.g. System.Timers.Timer if you want to run something in the background.

One thing you need to take into account when doing this in background threads, is that whenever you want to update some screen-element, you will have to ask the UI thread to do it for you (rather than the background thread). 
Read more about this here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

An even better way to do it (although you'll need to invest a bit more time right now) is to use async/await or BackgroundWorkers, but the way you've started implementing it can work too, with a bit of effort.

Hope this helps.